# imagemagick with php,wamp server giving problems

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick, wampserver

Im trying to use imagemagick with php.

Im using the following binary file : `ImageMagick-6.4.1-0-Q8-windows-dll.exe`

im using the following php extension : `php_imagick_dyn-Q8.dll`

I have copied the extension to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext`

I have edited the `php.ini` file located at `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0` and included the following line: `extension=php_imagick_dyn-Q8.dll`

I have installed imagemagick in : `C:/imagemagick`

I have set Environmental variable: `MAGICK_HOME` to `C:/imagemagick`

I have edited the `httpd.conf`file which is located at `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf` and included  : `SetEnv MAGICK_HOME “C:/imagemagick"` in it.

Im using `windows 7 service  pack 1`.
`Apache2.2.11` and 
`php5.3.0`

But when i start the wamp server i get the following error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this [.exe to install imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) ?

Comment: **I still get the same error.This thing is giving me headache.**